# Combination of Choosing Identical Items into Identical Slots

Tags: combinatorics

Renee has a bag of $6$ candies, $4$ of which are sweet and $2$ of which are sour. Jack picks two candies simultaneously and at random. What is the chance that exactly $1$ of the candies he has picked is sour?

I know the answer is $(4C_1)(2C_1)/(6C_2)=8/15$

My confusion is about why this approach is giving us the correct answer?

When I chose 2 candies out of the $6$, I assumed the "slots" they were going into were identical $\{\mathrm{Sour}, \mathrm{Sweet}\}=\{\mathrm{Sweet},\mathrm{Sour}\}$, kinda of like a card of poker. However unlike a poker deck, the candies are identical within each category. It doesn't matter if I got either $\mathrm{Sweet}\,_1$, $\mathrm{Sweet}\,_2$, $\mathrm{Sweet}\,_3$, $\mathrm{Sweet}\,_4$, its all the same thing. Same can be said about the sour candy.  Whenever I choose $r$ things from $n$ items, I am assuming the $r$ items are going to identical slots and the $n$ items are all different ${n_1,n_2,n_3...}$. So what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be clear that the answer to the probability problem does not change if each candy has a secret ID number written on it with invisible ink. The advantage of thinking of the candies are distinct is that it is clear that every pair of candies is **equally likely**.

We might only care about whether we get double sweet, mixed, or double sour. That changes the sample space. Instead of having $\binom{6}{2}$ elements, the sample space now has $3$ elements. Unfortunately, these $3$ elements are not equally likely. For example, it is intuitively clear that double sweet is substantially more likely than double sour.

Viewing the candies as having distinct ID numbers makes calculating the required probability a matter of counting. If we wish to think of the sample space as having $3$ elements, it is not clear how to compute the probabilities.